# x11 gnu/linux vlc can't find video window xcb_glx

Tags: linux, vlc-media-player, xorg

vlc is not able to play any videos. Currently I'm running Manjaro 18.0 xfce with x11 and vlc 3.0.4-7. My suspicion is that vlc can't find or is not configured to look for xcb_window and is instead trying to use xcb_glx. Here's the console output for `vlc -vvvv`

```
[00007f01d8058d20] main video output error: video output creation failed
[00007f01d80620a0] dbus_screensaver inhibit debug: got cookie 1747901769
[00007f01d80620a0] main inhibit debug: removing module "dbus_screensaver"
[00007f01d80a2aa0] qt window debug: releasing video...
[00005562013e9fd0] qt interface debug: Video is not needed anymore
[00007f01d80499b0] main spu text debug: removing module "freetype"
[00007f01d80c55d0] main scale debug: removing module "yuvp"
[00007f01d804e400] main scale debug: removing module "swscale"
[00007f0204c1ac00] main decoder error: failed to create video output
[00007f01d00499d0] main spu text debug: looking for text renderer module matching "any": 2 candidates
[00007f01d00499d0] freetype spu text debug: Building font databases.
[00007f01d00499d0] freetype spu text debug: Took -9372 microseconds
[00007f01d00499d0] main spu text debug: using text renderer module "freetype"
[00007f01d004e760] main scale debug: looking for video converter module matching "any": 23 candidates
[00007f01d004e760] swscale scale debug: 32x32 (32x32) chroma: YUVA -> 16x16 (16x16) chroma: RGBA with scaling using Bicubic (good quality)
[00007f01d004e760] main scale debug: using video converter module "swscale"
[00007f01d00c58d0] main scale debug: looking for video converter module matching "any": 23 candidates
[00007f01d00c58d0] yuvp scale debug: YUVP to YUVA converter
[00007f01d00c58d0] main scale debug: using video converter module "yuvp"
[00007f01d007cd90] main video output debug: Deinterlacing available
[00007f01d007cd90] main video output debug: deinterlace -1, mode auto, is_needed 0
[00007f01d00a2ee0] main window debug: looking for vout window module matching "qt,any": 6 candidates
[00007f01d00a2ee0] qt window debug: requesting video window...
[00007f01d00a2ee0] main window debug: using vout window module "qt"
[00007f01d00a0490] main inhibit debug: looking for inhibit module matching "any": 2 candidates
[00007f01d00a2ee0] main window debug: resized to 1920x798
[00007f01d00a0490] dbus_screensaver inhibit debug: found service org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver
[00007f01d00a0490] main inhibit debug: using inhibit module "dbus_screensaver"
[00007f01d00a2ee0] main window debug: resized to 1857x933
[00007f01d007cd90] main video output debug: Opening vout display wrapper
[00007f01c0001370] main vout display debug: looking for vout display module matching "xcb_glx": 14 candidates
[00007f01c0001370] main vout display debug: no vout display modules matched
[00007f01d007cd90] main video output error: video output creation failed
```

Here's the output for `vlc --list-verbose`

```
VLC media player 3.0.4 Vetinari (revision 3.0.4-0-gf615db6332)
  gather                 Gathering stream output
  stream_out_rtp         RTP stream output
  stream_out_rtp         RTSP VoD server
  record                 Record stream output
  description            Description stream output
  stream_out_chromaprint Chromaprint stream output
  display                Display stream output
  smem                   Stream output to memory buffer
  setid                  Change the id of an elementary stream
  setid                  Change the language of an elementary stream
  stream_out_chromecast  Chromecast stream output
  stream_out_chromecast  Chromecast stream output
  stream_out_chromecast  Chromecast stream output
  stats                  Writes statistic info about stream
  es                     Elementary stream output
  stream_out_transcode   Transcode stream output
  delay                  Delay a stream
  cycle                  Cyclic stream output
  duplicate              Duplicate stream output
  stream_out_standard    Standard stream output
  autodel                Automatically add/delete input streams
  bridge                 Bridge stream output
  bridge                 Bridge stream output
  bridge                 Bridge stream output
  dummy                  Dummy stream output
  mosaic_bridge          Mosaic bridge stream output
  stl                    EBU STL subtitles decoder
  svcdsub                Philips OGT (SVCD subtitle) decoder
  svcdsub                Philips OGT (SVCD subtitle) packetizer
  svgdec                 SVG video decoder
  oggspots               OggSpots video decoder
  oggspots               OggSpots video packetizer
  zvbi                   VBI and Teletext decoder
  faad                   AAC audio decoder (using libfaad2)
  opus                   Opus audio decoder
  opus                   Opus audio encoder
  libmpeg2               MPEG I/II video decoder (using libmpeg2)
  scte18                 SCTE-18 decoder
  theora                 Theora video decoder
  theora                 Theora video packetizer
  theora                 Theora video encoder
  dca                    DTS Coherent Acoustics audio decoder
  omxil                  Audio/Video decoder (using OpenMAX IL)
  omxil                  Audio/Video decoder (using OpenMAX IL)
  omxil                  Video encoder (using OpenMAX IL)
  cdg                    CDG video decoder
  subsdec                Text subtitle decoder
  flac                   Flac audio decoder
  flac                   Flac audio encoder
  a52                    ATSC A/52 (AC-3) audio decoder
  t140                   T.140 text encoder
  aribsub                ARIB subtitles decoder
  xwd                    XWD image decoder
  mpg123                 MPEG audio decoder using mpg123
  rawvideo               Pseudo raw video decoder
  rawvideo               Pseudo raw video packetizer
  araw                   Raw/Log Audio decoder
  araw                   Raw audio encoder
  kate                   Kate overlay decoder
  speex                  Speex audio decoder
  speex                  Speex audio packetizer
  speex                  Speex audio encoder
  aes3                   AES3/SMPTE 302M audio decoder
  aes3                   AES3/SMPTE 302M audio packetizer
  shine                  MP3 fixed point audio encoder
  rtpvideo               Raw video encoder for RTP
  x265                   H.265/HEVC encoder (x265)
  ttml                   TTML subtitles decoder
  ttml                   TTML demuxer
  vorbis                 Vorbis audio decoder
  vorbis                 Vorbis audio packetizer
  vorbis                 Vorbis audio encoder
  avcodec                FFmpeg audio/video decoder
  avcodec                FFmpeg audio/video decoder
  avcodec                FFmpeg audio/video decoder
  avcodec                FFmpeg audio/video encoder
  twolame                Libtwolame audio encoder
  spdif                  S/PDIF pass-through decoder
  jpeg                   JPEG image decoder
  jpeg                   JPEG image encoder
  spudec                 DVD subtitles decoder
  spudec                 DVD subtitles packetizer
  subsusf                USF subtitles decoder
  crystalhd              Crystal HD hardware video decoder
  scte27                 SCTE-27 decoder
  adpcm                  ADPCM audio decoder
  dvbsub                 DVB subtitles decoder
  dvbsub                 DVB subtitles encoder
  vaapi                  VA-API video decoder
  cc                     Closed Captions decoder
  x264                   H.264/MPEG-4 Part 10/AVC encoder (x264)
  edummy                 Dummy encoder
  uleaddvaudio           Ulead DV audio decoder
  ddummy                 Dummy decoder
  ddummy                 Dummy decoder
  ddummy                 Dummy decoder
  ddummy                 Dump decoder
  ddummy                 Dummy decoder
  ddummy                 Dummy decoder
  textst                 HDMV TextST subtitles decoder
  vaapi_drm              VA-API video decoder via DRM
  sdl_image              SDL_image video decoder
  png                    PNG video decoder
  png                    PNG video encoder
  cvdsub                 CVD subtitle decoder
  cvdsub                 Chaoji VCD subtitle packetizer
  lpcm                   Linear PCM audio decoder
  lpcm                   Linear PCM audio packetizer
  lpcm                   Linear PCM audio encoder
  substx3g               tx3g subtitles decoder
  webvtt                 WEBVTT subtitles decoder
  webvtt                 WEBVTT subtitles parser
  webvtt                 WEBVTT subtitles parser
  libass                 Subtitle renderers using libass
  g711                   G.711 decoder
  g711                   G.711 encoder
  wall                   Wall video filter
  panoramix              Panoramix: wall with overlap video filter
  clone                  Clone video filter
  mp4                    MP4 stream demuxer
  demuxdump              File dumper
  demux_cdg              CDG demuxer
  real                   Real demuxer
  vobsub                 Vobsub subtitles parser
  caf                    CAF demuxer
  mod                    MOD demuxer (libmodplug)
  directory              Directory import
  mpc                    MusePack demuxer
  demux_chromecast       Chromecast demux wrapper
  subtitle               Text subtitle parser
  mkv                    Matroska stream demuxer
  h26x                   H264 video demuxer
  h26x                   HEVC/H.265 video demuxer
  nsc                    Windows Media NSC metademux
  nsv                    NullSoft demuxer
  au                     AU demuxer
  nuv                    Nuv demuxer
  adaptive               Unified adaptive streaming for DASH/HLS
  image                  Image demuxer
  aiff                   AIFF demuxer
  ogg                    OGG demuxer
  es                     MPEG-I/II/4 / A52 / DTS / MLP audio
  es                     MPEG-4 video
  tta                    TTA demuxer
  rawaud                 Raw audio demuxer
  avi                    AVI demuxer
  pva                    PVA demuxer
  rawdv                  DV (Digital Video) demuxer
  noseek                 Seek prevention demux filter
  vc1                    VC1 video demuxer
  mpgv                   MPEG-I/II video demuxer
  sid                    C64 sid demuxer
  ts                     MPEG Transport Stream demuxer
  xa                     XA demuxer
  avformat               Avformat demuxer
  avformat               Avformat muxer
  ps                     MPEG-PS demuxer
  ps                     MPEG-PS demuxer
  smf                    SMF demuxer
  wav                    WAV demuxer
  playlist               Playlist
  playlist               M3U playlist import
  playlist               RAM playlist import
  playlist               PLS playlist import
  playlist               B4S playlist import
  playlist               DVB playlist import
  playlist               Podcast parser
  playlist               XSPF playlist import
  playlist               New winamp 5.2 shoutcast import
  playlist               ASX playlist import
  playlist               Kasenna MediaBase parser
  playlist               QuickTime Media Link importer
  playlist               Dummy IFO demux
  playlist               iTunes Music Library importer
  playlist               WPL playlist import
  voc                    VOC demuxer
  ty                     TY Stream audio/video demux
  rawvid                 Raw video demuxer
  asf                    ASF/WMV demuxer
  flacsys                FLAC demuxer
  demux_stl              EBU STL subtitles parser
  mjpeg                  M-JPEG camera demuxer
  diracsys               Dirac video demuxer
  vdpau_adjust           VDPAU adjust video filter
  vdpau_deinterlace      VDPAU deinterlacing filter
  vdpau_chroma           VDPAU surface conversions
  vdpau_chroma           VDPAU surface conversions
  vdpau_display          VDPAU output
  vdpau_avcodec          VDPAU video decoder
  vdpau_sharpen          VDPAU sharpen video filter
  mosaic                 Mosaic video sub source
  audiobargraph_v        Audio Bar Graph Video sub source
  audiobargraph_v        Audio Bar Graph Video sub source
  marq                   Marquee display
  subsdelay              Subtitle delay
  remoteosd              Remote-OSD over VNC
  dynamicoverlay         Dynamic video overlay
  logo                   Logo sub source
  logo                   Logo video filter
  rss                    RSS and Atom feed display
  blend                  Video pictures blending
  hqdn3d                 High Quality 3D Denoiser filter
  scale                  Video scaling filter
  scene                  Scene video filter
  posterize              Posterize video filter
  motiondetect           Motion detect video filter
  postproc               Video post processing filter
  gaussianblur           Gaussian blur video filter
  colorthres             Color threshold filter
  wave                   Wave video filter
  fps                    FPS conversion video filter
  adjust                 Image properties filter
  grain                  Grain video filter
  deinterlace            Deinterlacing video filter
  antiflicker            antiflicker video filter
  transform              Video transformation filter
  mirror                 Mirror video filter
  ball                   Ball video filter
  magnify                Magnify/Zoom interactive video filter
  extract                Extract RGB component video filter
  puzzle                 Puzzle interactive game video filter
  alphamask              Alpha mask video filter
  vhs                    VHS movie effect video filter
  oldmovie               Old movie effect video filter
  erase                  Erase video filter
  freeze                 Freezing interactive video filter
  motionblur             Motion blur filter
  croppadd               Video cropping filter
  sepia                  Sepia video filter
  gradient               Gradient video filter
  edgedetection          Edge detection video filter
  blendbench             Blending benchmark filter
  invert                 Invert video filter
  canvas                 Canvas video filter
  psychedelic            Psychedelic video filter
  anaglyph               Convert 3D picture to anaglyph image video filter
  gradfun                Gradfun video filter
  bluescreen             Bluescreen video filter
  sharpen                Sharpen video filter
  ripple                 Ripple video filter
  rotate                 Rotate video filter
  dtv                    Digital Television and Radio
  idummy                 Dummy input
  attachment             Attachment input
  dc1394                 IIDC Digital Camera (FireWire) input
  imem                   Memory input
  imem                   Memory input
  timecode               Time code subpicture elementary stream generator
  access_alsa            ALSA audio capture
  udp                    UDP input
  access_realrtsp        Real RTSP
  pulsesrc               PulseAudio input
  vcd                    VCD input
  nfs                    NFS input
  concat                 Concatenated inputs
  satip                  SAT>IP Receiver Plugin
  sdp                    Session Description Protocol
  cdda                   Audio CD input
  cdda                   Audio CD input
  dv1394                 Digital Video (Firewire/ieee1394) input
  access_mms             Microsoft Media Server (MMS) input
  dvdread                DVDRead Input (no menu support)
  dvb                    DVB input with v4l2 support
  vdr                    VDR recordings
  linsys_sdi             SDI Input
  linsys_sdi             SDI Demux
  libbluray              Blu-ray Disc support (libbluray)
  libbluray              BluRay demuxer
  dvdnav                 DVDnav Input
  dvdnav                 DVDnav demuxer
  live555                RTP/RTSP/SDP demuxer (using Live555)
  live555                RTSP/RTP access and demux
  shm                    Shared memory framebuffer
  linsys_hdsdi           HD-SDI Input
  http                   HTTP input
  avio                   libavformat AVIO access
  avio                   libavformat AVIO access output
  smb                    SMB input
  filesystem             File input
  filesystem             File input
  sftp                   SFTP input
  access_mtp             MTP input
  imem_access            In-memory stream input
  rtp                    Real-Time Protocol (RTP) input
  access                 HTTPS input
  tcp                    TCP input
  v4l2                   Video4Linux input
  v4l2                   Video4Linux compressed A/V input
  v4l2                   Video4Linux radio tuner
  ftp                    FTP input
  ftp                    FTP upload output
  gestures               Mouse gestures control interface
  dummy                  Dummy interface
  lirc                   Infrared remote control interface
  dbus                   D-Bus control interface
  oldrc                  Remote control interface
  netsync                Network synchronization
  hotkeys                Hotkeys management interface
  motion                 motion control interface
  xcb_hotkeys            Global Hotkeys interface
  gnutls                 GNU TLS transport layer security
  gnutls                 GNU TLS server
  vorepository           addons.videolan.org addons finder
  vorepository           single .vlp archive addons finder
  stats                  Stats encoder function
  stats                  Stats decoder function
  stats                  Stats decoder function
  stats                  Stats decoder function
  stats                  Stats demux function
  rtsp                   Legacy RTSP VoD server
  logger                 File logging
  xdg                    XDG screen saver inhibition
  dbus_screensaver       D-Bus screen saver inhibition
  xml                    XML Parser (using libxml2)
  xml                    XML Parser (using libxml2)
  export                 export
  export                 M3U playlist export
  export                 M3U8 playlist export
  export                 XSPF playlist export
  export                 HTML playlist export
  fingerprinter          Track fingerprinter (based on Acoustid)
  audioscrobbler         Submission of played songs to last.fm
  fsstorage              Addons local storage installer
  fsstorage              Addons local storage lister
  adummy                 Dummy audio output
  alsa                   ALSA audio output
  afile                  File audio output
  amem                   Audio memory output
  pulse                  Pulseaudio audio output
  sndio                  OpenBSD sndio audio output
  lua                    Lua interpreter
  lua                    Lua HTTP
  lua                    Command-line interface
  lua                    Lua Telnet
  lua                    Fetch meta data using lua scripts
  lua                    Read meta data using lua scripts
  lua                    Lua Playlist Parser Interface
  lua                    Fetch artwork using lua scripts
  lua                    Lua Extension
  lua                    Lua SD Module
  lua                    Lua interpreter
  tdummy                 Dummy font renderer
  freetype               Freetype2 font renderer
  glspectrum             3D OpenGL spectrum visualization
  visual                 Visualizer filter
  vaapi_filters          Video Accelerated API filters
  vaapi_filters          Video Accelerated API filters
  vaapi_filters          Video Accelerated API filters
  vaapi_filters          Video Accelerated API filters
  vaapi_filters          Video Accelerated API filters
  vaapi_filters          Video Accelerated API filters
  integer_mixer          Integer audio volume
  float_mixer            Single precision audio volume
  taglib                 taglib
  taglib                 taglib
  folder                 Folder meta data
  podcast                Podcasts
  podcast                Podcasts
  sap                    Network streams (SAP)
  sap                    Network streams (SAP)
  sap                    SDP Descriptions parser
  udev                   Video capture (Video4Linux)
  udev                   Audio capture (ALSA)
  udev                   Discs
  udev                   Video capture (Video4Linux)
  upnp                   Universal Plug'n'Play
  upnp                   Universal Plug'n'Play
  upnp                   Universal Plug'n'Play
  mediadirs              My Videos
  mediadirs              My Music
  mediadirs              My Pictures
  mediadirs              My Videos
  mtp                    MTP devices
  mtp                    MTP devices
  xcb_apps               Screen capture
  xcb_apps               Screen capture
  pulselist              Audio capture (PulseAudio)
  pulselist              Audio capture (PulseAudio)
  microdns               mDNS Network Discovery
  microdns               mDNS Network Discovery
  microdns               mDNS Renderer Discovery
  microdns               mDNS Network Discovery
  avahi                  Zeroconf services
  avahi                  Zeroconf services
  skins2                 Skinnable Interface
  skins2                 Skinnable Interface
  qt                     Qt interface
  qt                     Dialogs provider
  qt                     Qt interface
  ncurses                Ncurses interface
  chorus_flanger         Sound Delay
  tospdif                Audio filter for A/52/DTS->S/PDIF encapsulation
  samplerate             Secret Rabbit Code (libsamplerate) resampler
  samplerate             Secret Rabbit Code (libsamplerate) resampler
  scaletempo_pitch       Pitch Shifter
  dolby                  Simple decoder for Dolby Surround encoded streams
  stereo_widen           Simple stereo widening effect
  speex_resampler        Speex resampler
  speex_resampler        Speex resampler
  normvol                Volume normalizer
  simple_channel_mixer   Audio filter for simple channel mixing
  headphone              Headphone virtual spatialization effect
  mad                    MPEG audio layer I/II/III decoder
  audiobargraph_a        Audio part of the BarGraph function
  equalizer              Equalizer with 10 bands
  audio_format           Audio filter for PCM format conversion
  soxr                   soxr
  soxr                   soxr
  scaletempo             Audio tempo scaler synched with rate
  karaoke                Simple Karaoke filter
  mono                   Stereo to mono downmixer
  gain                   Gain control filter
  trivial                Audio filter for trivial channel mixing
  compressor             Dynamic range compressor
  ugly                   Nearest-neighbor audio resampler
  ugly                   Nearest-neighbor audio resampler
  spatializer            Audio Spatializer
  remap                  Audio channel remapper
  param_eq               Parametric Equalizer
  vc1                    VC-1 packetizer
  mlp                    MLP/TrueHD parser
  copy                   Copy packetizer
  dirac                  Dirac packetizer
  mpegvideo              MPEG-I/II video packetizer
  packetizer_avparser    avparser packetizer
  hevc                   HEVC/H.265 video packetizer
  a52                    A/52 audio packetizer
  mpeg4audio             MPEG4 audio packetizer
  h264                   H.264 video packetizer
  mpeg4video             MPEG4 video packetizer
  flac                   Flac audio packetizer
  dts                    DTS audio packetizer
  mpegaudio              MPEG audio layer I/II/III packetizer
  ps                     PS muxer
  dummy                  Dummy/Raw muxer
  mux_ts                 TS muxer (libdvbpsi)
  mux_ogg                Ogg/OGM muxer
  asf                    ASF muxer
  wav                    WAV muxer
  mp4                    MP4/MOV muxer
  mp4                    Fragmented and streamable MP4 muxer
  mpjpeg                 Multipart JPEG muxer
  avi                    AVI muxer
  secret                 Secrets are stored via libsecret
  kwallet                Secrets are stored via KWallet
  memory                 Secrets are stored in memory
  file                   Secrets are stored on a file without any encryption
  gles2                  OpenGL for Embedded Systems 2 video output
  glconv_vaapi_x11       VA-API OpenGL surface converter for X11
  yuv                    YUV video output
  wl_shm                 Wayland shared memory video output
  glconv_vaapi_wl        VA-API OpenGL surface converter for Wayland
  egl_x11                EGL extension for OpenGL
  egl_x11                EGL extension for OpenGL
  xcb_xv                 XVideo output (XCB)
  gl                     OpenGL video output
  xcb_window             X11 video window (XCB)
  xcb_window             Embedded window video
  caca                   Color ASCII art video output
  glx                    GLX extension for OpenGL
  egl_wl                 EGL extension for OpenGL
  egl_wl                 EGL extension for OpenGL
  fb                     GNU/Linux framebuffer video output
  wl_shell               Wayland shell surface
  glconv_vaapi_drm       VA-API OpenGL surface converter for DRM
  xdg_shell              XDG shell surface
  vmem                   Video memory output
  vdummy                 Dummy video output
  vdummy                 Statistics video output
  xcb_x11                X11 video output (XCB)
  flaschen               Flaschen-Taschen video output
  glconv_vdpau           VDPAU OpenGL surface converter
  aa                     ASCII-art video output
  i420_rgb_mmx           MMX I420,IYUV,YV12 to RV15,RV16,RV24,RV32
```

...
Had to trim the output

Answer (score 0):

Changing the default setting->Output Modules: Video Output Module from automatic to x11 video module (XCB) fixed this issue.